# How can i keep __proto__ prototypes of object missing on req.body?

Tags: javascript, axios, prototype, body-parser

How can I send an Object with prototyped methods to my backend without loosing the methods?

I created an object and prototyped two methods on it:

```
    function News(news) {
        this.text = news.text
    }
    
    News.prototype = {
        showText: function() {
            console.log(this.text)
        },
        createText: function() {
            // DO STUFF
        }
    }
```

The Object then looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvWok.png)

```
obj
News {text: "hello world"}
text: "hello world"
__proto__:
createText: ƒ ()
showText: ƒ ()
__proto__: Object
```

I am then sending this obj via **axios** (+ body-parser) to my backend.

But on my backend the received object on `req.body` is just:

```
req.body { text: 'hello world' }
```

So probably I am misunderstanding something here, but is body-parser cutting of the __ proto __ of the object? Should I send data in a different way to keep the prototypes of the JavaScript object? Or is there a something basic I did not consider?

Just in case, this is body-parser config on my app.js:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: '50mb' }))
```

And axios:

```
const service = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '/api' : 'http://localhost:5000/api',
  withCredentials: true
})
```

Comment: you cannot pass prototypes in req.body you can assign it to a different variable

Comment: you're implementing a prototype pollution vulnerability, not at all wise. just post up the string and/or json and get from req.body

Comment: It doesn't matter that the methods are inherited. What's much more important is that **you cannot send functions in JSON**! Your objects are *always* going to loose their methods. Instead, you should have the `News` code in the backend as well, and construct a new instance (with the trusted code) from the JSON text.

Comment: Al right, that already helps a lot! Thank you <3